# UITextView autocompletion of custom text

Tags: ios, uitextview, autocompletetextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have `UITextView` in which as the user types I would like to suggest a few words (like in a popup) as is displayed for misspelled words.

There are custom words that I have in a an array which should be used as suggestions

For example if the user starts to type "carpen" I would like to suggest "carpenter1", "carpenter2", "carpenter3", so that the user can select any one of the 3 suggestions or choose to type a new one.

**`UITextChecker`**

Is `completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:` something that I can use ? If so how can I make pass the array to the popup ?

**Question:**

1. How would I be able to achieve something like what is shown in the image ?
2. Let me know if there is a different approach

[image]

Comment: Hi please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578079/objective-c-change-the-autocompletion-source-for-uitextfield